# Docker with springboot and mysql issue with linking and running

Tags: mysql, docker, spring-boot

I am trying to run a spring-boot application (which connects to a mySQL database) as a docker container (so basically 2 containers linked together).

But since the mySQL docker container is different, I am having a tough time linking the two containers. I tried to externalize the application.properties but then I am not able to run it by passing the argument to external application properties.

Is there a way to connect these two containers efficiently?

Here is my app properties and the dockerfile

application.properties:

```
spring.application.name=customer-service
server.port:8203

#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://demo-mysql:3306/bankbotdb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bankbotdb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=***
spring.datasource.password =*******
...
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/nlp-bot-customer-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/micro-services/
ADD config/application.properties /opt/micro-services/config/
WORKDIR /opt/micro-services/
EXPOSE 8203
ENTRYPOINT [“java”, “-jar”,”nlp-bot-customer-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar — spring.config.name=application — spring.config.location=classpath:/op/micro-services/config”]
```

Comment: Could you please show how do you start this container? I think the case might be that your container does not have connection with host's 3306 port.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Hence I need a way to find that connection. here is how I ran it (see below)

Comment: docker run -it \
    --name bot-customer-service \
 -p 8203:8203 \
 --link demo-mysql \
 bot-customer-service

Comment: `--link` option is marked as _not recommended_. You should try [creating your own network](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/#connect-containers) instead.

Comment: Also, you can try to connect both of your containers to the **host network** using `--network host` while running. This will make your containers use the host's network and therefore, ports that you're using in them will be accessible in your network. This is not the best idea in the production environment, as you should block access to your database from outside of your application, but it will allow you to check if it's not the matter of your application configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your application.properties: `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bankbotdb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false`

In a docker environment as you're using "localhost" will refer to the container itself  (in this case your "bot-customer-service" container) unless you're using host mode which is not recommended.

To fix this you should change the line to `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://demo-mysql:3306/bankbotdb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false` (based on your comment). Change demo-mysql to whatever you call your mysql container when you start it.

I would recommend using [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to help with the overview and reproducibility when orchestrating your services.

Comment: Thanks Mikael, but there is a problem in that! I am not able to compile my spring-boot application (to create the jar referred in the Dockerfile) when I change the spring.datasource.url. So is there a way I could do it while building my docker image?